# ffmpeg .264 to .avi

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, avi, video-conversion

I try to convert .264 file to .avi
To do it I use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i source.264 -c:v libx264 -an dest.avi
```

It works, but has worse quality that source file. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `-c:v copy` instead to copy the source stream without re-encoding.